# Any active business network community in KL Malaysia?

Tags: working, business, socializing, malaysia

I have been KL for 6 months now. I could not network through out work due to my hectic work schedule, setting up the new team and work location changing few times etc. I barely have no connection no friends wasting times being bored alone. I was wondering how they build their biz connection here other than work places from other companies making valuable connections that can be your friends as well as mutually beneficial connections that turning into prospect job opportunity in the future for example US chamber event party, biz social meet up(meetup.com for KL was not very intriguing to me though) etc.

Comment: This could be a starter [Quora: What are some popular large-business networking events in Malaysia?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-popular-large-business-networking-events-in-Malaysia)